# Continuous differentiability of functions of one real variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and let $f:U\to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function. Define the function $F:U\times U\to\mathbb R$ by $$F(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}&\textrm{ in case }x\ne y\\
f'(x)&\textrm{ in case }x=y.
\end{cases}$$
Then I notice that $f'$ is continuous if and only if $F$ is continuous. So this gives a criterion for the continuous differentiability of functions of one real variable. Is there a related criterion for functions of several variables?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $f'$ is continuous if $F$ is continuous? As $F(x,x) = f'(x)$, what exactly has your method going for it?

Comment: If $F$ is continuous then so is the composite $x\mapsto(x,x)\mapsto F(x,x)$ and hence $f'$ is continuous.

Comment: But that's essentially not a single bit easier than just checking for continuity on $f'$ itself